# Only way to write this SQL JOIN question?

Tags: sql

I wrote this sql query and it seems to work great but im not sure if it is the correct way to write it or if there is another better way to write it:

```
 SELECT 
         art.artid, users.userid
     FROM 
         art LEFT JOIN users 
     ON 
         art.userid = users.userid 
     WHERE 
         (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM art WHERE art.userid = users.userid) > 5 AND
             users.active = '1' AND 
             art.active = '1' AND
             art.status = '0' AND
             art.pricesek > 0  GROUP BY users.userid ORDER BY RAND()
```

It gets the users from users table that are active and has 5 or more artworks in the art table. It also checks to see that artwork is active, status of artwork is set to 0 "for sale" and price is more then 0. Then it groups results by userid in a random order.

Is this the correct way to write this or is there another way.

"*All input is hardcoded so no userinput will be sent into database, so not worried about injections (should i be worried even if its hardcoded?)*."

Comment: If the output is correct, and it is not too slow, then: Why should it not be the correct way?

Comment: You did forget to add the dtabase you are using.  Most SQL database do not accept selecting `art.artid, users.userid` and grouping by just onde of those fields (`users.uderid`), because it will be unclear which value of `art.artid` to return. Should it return the minimal value, the max value or some random value?

Comment: You could use a natural left join so you don't have to spell out the keys.  If you use a common table expression you can that outer query both for the result and to generate the count (which is usually just expressed as select count(*) c from table group by user_id having c > 5.  Why do you order by rand()?  You could do that on the client side, too.

Comment: Yes, @Luuk's comment is valid.  If the syntax is not invalid and the query results returned are correct, then there's not really anything to say that it's "incorrect".  When people wonder whether they are doing the "right" thing, often it's because they want to know that the query will run in the most efficient way - but in truth, that has to do with more things that just the query itself.  How large are the database tables themselves?  Which, if any, of the query columns are indexed?  I will admit that I'm not completely sure about you're use of ORDER BY RAND(), but again, it is valid syntax

Comment: Does this even run? You can't group by one column and not aggregate the other, the count should be a `having` without any need to query the table a second time, the use of `rand()` would have no effect on most RDBMS as it will be evaluated once and the same value used for all rows.

Comment: Note: the `users.active = '1'` is invariant in the subquery; you could hoist it to the main query.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Even if I did not get any error with the query I wrote, I did change it to how Gordon Linoff wrote it. Regarding art.artid in my question, I do not know why I added it at all as I dont even need to see it. I only need userid. However, I think I should review my old sql skills and refresh my memory a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change in your code. Instead of using `(SELECT COUNT (1) FROM art WHERE art.userid = users.userid)> 5` I put it in `Having clause`.

```
SELECT art.artid, users.userid
FROM  art LEFT JOIN users ON art.userid = users.userid 
WHERE  users.active = '1' AND   art.active = '1' AND
       art.status = '0' AND art.pricesek > 0  
GROUP BY users.userid, art.artid
HAVING COUNT(users.userid) > 5
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has problems at many levels.  The most obvious is that the `GROUP BY` clause is inconsistent with the `SELECT`.  That *should* be generating an error.

> It gets the users from users table that are active and has 5 or more artworks in the art table.

I would instead suggest aggregating the `art` table *before* joining:

```
SELECT u.userid
FROM users u JOIN
     (SELECT a.userid, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM art a
      WHERE a.active = 1 AND
            a.status = 0 AND
            a.pricesek > 0
      GROUP BY a.userid
     ) a 
     ON a.userid = u.userid 
WHERE a.cnt > 5 AND u.active = 1
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Notes:

- `LEFT JOIN` is not appropriate.  In order to count the number of artworks, the `JOIN` must find at least 1 (really 6) matching rows.
- It makes no sense to return `a.artid`.  If you need an example, you could use `min(a.artid)` in the subquery.  If you want all of them, then you would need to specify how to return them, but a JSON, array, or string aggregation function would be used n the subquery.
- The values "1" and "0" look like numbers, so I removed the single quotes, so I assume the columns are numbers.  Compare numbers to numbers and strings to strings.  Try to avoid mixing the two.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this one. I will use this. I honestly dont know why I even added "artid" to the query as I dont even need to see it. I only need the userid :)